# coredump in beam.smp OTP-20.0

Tags: erlang

All,

I encountered a crash problem when using OTP20.0. Can anybody give me some clues about this?

(gdb) bt

## 0  proc_btm_rbt_delete (root=0x7f9b39958ea0, n=0x7f9cc61146d8) at beam/erl_rbtree.h:689

## 1  0x0000000000597e40 in bif_timer_timeout (vbtmp=0x7f9cc61146d8) at beam/erl_hl_timer.c:1291

## 2  tw_bif_timer_timeout (vbtmp=0x7f9cc61146d8) at beam/erl_hl_timer.c:1325

## 3  0x000000000051ef82 in timeout_timer (tiw=0x7f9cc4a8ff40, curr_time=2610876354489461) at beam/time.c:755

## 4  erts_bump_timers (tiw=0x7f9cc4a8ff40, curr_time=2610876354489461) at beam/time.c:954

## 5  0x00000000004fe04e in scheduler_wait (fcalls=, esdp=0x7f9cc47c2e80, rq=) at beam/erl_process.c:3548

## 6  0x0000000000504642 in erts_schedule (esdp=, p=, calls=) at beam/erl_process.c:10517

## 7  0x0000000000444445 in process_main (x_reg_array=, f_reg_array=0x7f9cc5dc2140) at beam/beam_emu.c:1353

## 8  0x00000000004f41f9 in sched_thread_func (vesdp=0x7f9cc47c2e80) at beam/erl_process.c:8877

## 9  0x000000000064f7ca in thr_wrapper (vtwd=) at pthread/ethread.c:118

## 10 0x000000321f0079d1 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0

## 11 0x000000321ece8b7d in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved with this fix.

https://github.com/erlang/otp/commit/f4def22e9a7c8b83d3bba4032b3d48571086224e#diff-179a47fa3222d4aabac7e6f31388a2b2